# CRUD operations on a prepopulated SQLite database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have successfully implemented a prepopulated database using SQLite Asset Helper and performed a query to list the names of my objects in the table using this [tutorial](http://www.javahelps.com/2015/04/import-and-use-external-database-in.html). I would however like to add CRUD functions to the android application to Add, Delete and Insert new objects. How can I do that?

DatabaseOpenHelper.java

```
import android.content.Context;

import com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper;

public class DatabaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteAssetHelper {
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "camera1.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

public DatabaseOpenHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
   }


}
```

DatabaseAccess.java

```
  import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DatabaseAccess {
private SQLiteOpenHelper openHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase database;
private static DatabaseAccess instance;

/**
 * Private constructor to aboid object creation from outside classes.
 *
 * @param context
 */
private DatabaseAccess(Context context) {
    this.openHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(context);
}

/**
 * Return a singleton instance of DatabaseAccess.
 *
 * @param context the Context
 * @return the instance of DabaseAccess
 */
public static DatabaseAccess getInstance(Context context) {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new DatabaseAccess(context);
    }
    return instance;
}

/**
 * Open the database connection.
 */
public void open() {
    this.database = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

/**
 * Close the database connection.
 */
public void close() {
    if (database != null) {
        this.database.close();
    }
}

/**
 * Read all quotes from the database.
 *
 * @return a List of quotes
 */
public List<String> getQuotes() {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT cameraname FROM camera", null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        list.add(cursor.getString(0));
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    return list;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this you need to copy your database into a device:

```
private static void copyDatabase(Context context) throws IOException {
    InputStream myInput = context.getResources().openRawResource(
            R.raw.database);
    String outFileName = getFullDbName(context);
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();
}
```

Then just open the database as usual:

```
mSqlite = new SqliteHelper(context, getFullDbName(context), null,
            DATABASE_VERSION);
```

After that you can just write whatever raw query you want.